# Problem using jQuery Cycle with 'all' fx

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I've recently finished a website.

I'm using jQuery Cycle for some random effects on the home page, but i had some problems.

Here the page : http://www.add-genealogie.com

I've placed 6 containers in the center of the page, with the same 12 pictures but with a shift of one photo, so there is not the same pictures on different containers.

But I have a problem, after about 30 seconds more or less, sometimes, one (or more) container is completely empty or sometime the picture isn't transitioning, so she is doubled.

I've tried to remove the maximum effect of jQuery Cycle, i've also trying with the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery Cycle, but nothing changes.

Do you have an idea where the problem could come.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.